# Why are the majority of patients with Edwards Syndrome females?

Tags: data, ovum-egg-oocyte, chromosomes

There is a larger incidence of female patients with Trisomy 18 that occurs mostly because of non-disjunction in the meiosis of oocytes. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/943463-overview#a6), the ratio of affected females/males differs when you look at liveborn or prenatal infants, which indicates a prenatal selection against males (*i.e.* more males are spontaneously aborted).

The article links to more references for further reading.